# Flutter create horizontal ListView with Magnifier

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, widget

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

So a horizontal `ListView` with a simple `TextWidget` inside of it. But I am stuck because I don't know how to create this *magnifier-effect*. They `greyView` can simply be created and put behind the `ListView`. But for the *selectedItem* the `fontSize` should change from *19* to *28*.

The only thing I found when searching for this was [ListWheelScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html), which has a `magnifier` but it is not quite what I need here.

Any idea how this can be achieved? Let me know if you need any more info.

**Screenshot explanation:**

The screenshot is the whole width so the highlighted item is in the center. The listView is from the left of the screen to the red line. Let's say the items are item = [widget(text: 2019), widget(text: 2020), widget(text: 2021), the screenshot should be the outcome. And it the user should be able to scroll to the left (ealier years)

Comment: When you say `magnify`, you mean scale up right? Do you magnify the item in the center of the screen or selected item? What's the idea?

Comment: @YoBo I updated my question. And yes, I mean scale up.